# jQuery check if selects have options

Tags: jquery, html

I have a random count of selects on page with the same class e.g. `.selectWidth` and I need to check which select has not any options and for each select with no options do same function.

Answer (score 1):

You can select which has no option like following.

```
$('.selectWidth:not(:has(option))')
```

You can iterate through these using each like below.

```
$('.selectWidth:not(:has(option))').each(function() {
    // do you stuff
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter()`

#### jQuery

```
$('.selectWidth').filter(function(){
    return this.options.length === 0;
}).each(function(){
    // do something
});
```

#### HTML

```
<select class="selectWidth"></select>
<select class="selectWidth">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<select class="selectWidth">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<select class="selectWidth"></select>
<select class="selectWidth"></select>
```